# Swift navigate to View from notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am making an iOS application. Where I have made that I get notification when near certain places. And that works fine. But I then want it to navigate to a certain view when I press the notification.
I am thinking just like when I get a sms. I press that notification for the sms and it then navigate me to the correct sms conversation.

Answer (score 1):

When application receives a push notification, a method in UIApplicationDelegate is called. The notification needs to be handled differently depending on what state your app is in when it’s received:

> If app wasn’t running and the user launches it by tapping the push
>   notification, the push notification is passed to your app in the
>   launchOptions of

```
 application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)
```

> If app was running and in the foreground, the push notification
>   will not be shown this function will call immediately

```
 application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)
```

> If app was running or suspended in the background and the user brings
>   it to the foreground by tapping the push notification, this function
>   will be called.

```
application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)
```

So you can change the root view controller on these functions like this :-

```
    if let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [String: AnyObject] {
       //Change your root view controller
     }
```

This checks whether the value for UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey exists in launchOptions. If it does, this will be the push notification payload you sent.

Comment: So this would be in my AppDelegate I should handle it? Is that correct understood?
Should it also be there the func for creating the notification is? Right now it is in getting called in mainViewController.

Comment: Not In main view controller, That's wrong. Go through with this tutorial's final part. You will get the idea.   https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Comment: And it is UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification) I use for making the notification.

To be more exact it is iBeacon I use, so when I get close to a iBeacon I want it to make a notification. And then I have a call to my server with the ID from the iBeacon and get a respond back to show some content depending on that. But that is then showed in a different View than the MainView.

But thanks for the input and the guide. I will try look at it and see if I can get it to work correct.

Comment: I think it has the same concept. Here is a useful link   https://www.raywenderlich.com/101891/ibeacons-tutorial-ios-swift

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple class to navigate to any view controller in the view hierarchy from anywhere in one line of code by just passing the class type, so the code you'll write will be also decoupled from the view hierarchy itself, for instance:

```
Navigator.find(MyViewController.self)?.doSomethingSync()
Navigator.navigate(to: MyViewController.self)?.doSomethingSync()
```

..or you can execute methods asynchronously on the main thread also:

```
Navigator.navigate(to: MyViewController.self) { (MyViewControllerContainer, MyViewControllerInstance) in
    MyViewControllerInstance?.doSomethingAsync()
}
```

Here the GitHub project link: https://github.com/oblq/Navigator